# Powershell WCF Response (Headers and Cookies)

Tags: wcf, powershell, cookies

Using Powershell, how do I connect to a WCF web service using New-WebServiceProxy, and retrieve the response header information including cookie data?  I have scoured the net and can't find any relevant information, other than stepping away from use of New-WebServiceProxy.

My current PS script looks like...

```
$authSvc = New-WebServiceProxy –Uri ‘http://myserver/Services/AuthenticationService.svc?WSDL’

$LoginResults = $true
$authSvc.Login('user1', 'abc123', $null, $true, $true, [ref] $LoginResults, [ref] $null)
```

... Seems there must be additional hooks into the New-WebServiceProxy that expose the header data, but I can't seem to identify it.  Using C# (just a test console app), I have been able to invoke this web service and retrieve cookie data, so I know the service is functioning correctly.

Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you are passing arguments in incorrect order? run just `$authSvc.Login` and it will return _OverloadDefinitions_

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Raf.  I tried and found no other overloads.  I determined $LoginResults was always false because I used double quotes.  I have updated my original question so it has the correct single quotes.

Comment: I have learned that single quotes will not interpret variables with a $ in them, whereas double quotes will.  My test password included a dollar sign, so it thought it was a null variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I think I have an answer to my own question.  Placing here for others trying the same thing.

The trick is to use the CookieContainer object which is intrinsic to the New-WebServiceProxy object.  The CookieContainer has a CookieCollection in it.  This collection can be enumerated.  Elaborating on my example in the question, I show how to expose cookie information returned from the web service call...

```
$authSvc = New-WebServiceProxy –Uri ‘http://myserver/Services/AuthenticationService.svc?WSDL’
$authSvc.CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer

$LoginResults = $true
$authSvc.Login('user1', 'abc123', $null, $true, $true, [ref] $LoginResults, [ref] $null)

$CookieCollection = $authSvc.CookieContainer.GetCookies(‘http://myserver/Services/AuthenticationService.svc?WSDL’)

foreach($cookie in $CookieCollection)
{
    echo $cookie.Name
    echo $cookie.Value
}
```

If I use the Get-Member method of the service...

```
$authSvc | Get-Member
```

... I then can see all the exposed methods the service allows.  The CookieContainer happens to be one of these.  Other relevant properties exposed are (but not limited to)...

- ClientCertificates
- Credentials
- RequestEncoding
- SoapVersion
- Url
- UserAgent